# Ionic 1 : API request not working on some device

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, google-play

my new app is release on the google play store.

But on some device, the app don't make the http requests on my external api (for the data).

Work find on my Nexus 5, Galaxy S7, One Plus 2.

But tried to download and install on an Nexus 5 X, Wiko etc, I can lauch the app but I only have my internal data (image etc).

Any issue on this ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to answer this question, but have you checked the android version of these devices. My personal experiences was since Android 5 and onward have better supports of ionic and api(wp-rest-api) calls. But on 4.4 & 4.2 sometimes the contents was not visible and I was forced to implement an auto refresh function in my controller.

Comment: My Nexus 5 running on Android M (6.0.1) and work fine.
Nexus 5x running on Nougat (7.0) don't work.
Galaxy S7 running on Nougat work..

So...

Comment: I am not sure then, but have you checked the Android sdk manager? have you installed desired packages and tools for Android 7? I am not sure but I think the API version is 24 for Android 7

Comment: I have to install all Android SDK starting 14 to 25 ?
And then build my APK after ?

Comment: If your application is working on Andorid 6, then you have already installed 23, but it depends on what version of Andorid you want to have the support. you just need to open sdk manager and apply new updates in tools and api packages. My personal experience was Android 4.2 and before don't have good support of ionic. I hope this fix the problem

Comment: I would like to support all version since Android 4 or 4.2

Comment: then yes, try to update api package version 14 to 25 and tools package

Comment: On my SDK list on Android Studio i have installed versions :

25, 22, 21.

Should I install all other starting to API level 14 ?

Comment: Ok i restart the app on the Nexus 5X and it was ok. That what u called force refresh ?

But this trick didn't work on 4.X version

Comment: -yes you have to install all API packages to 14
-By force refresh I mean having a function which be called by it self, so that you make sure the data are called in you app, something like

$scope.doRefresh = function(){
YOUR API CALL AND PROMISE
};

  $scope.doRefresh();

Comment: Thanks, 'ill try tonight :) 

And i just have to edit my config xml for the version of release and lauch 
"cordova build --release android"

? 

Or again zipalign etc ?